# how to copy row from one table to another before update on specific column in sybase trigger?

Tags: sql, database, triggers, sap-ase

I want to copy a row from one table to other table before an update happens on specific column. this column named `StartDateTime_`  in my table.
can anyone correct this trigger if it is not correct or need optimisation.

```
CREATE TRIGGER PeriodicHistory_TR_U ON order_db..Periodic
FOR UPDATE
AS IF update(StartDateTime_)
begin
        declare @Identity_;
        declare @Version_;
        DECLARE @Revision_;
        declare @Identifier_;
        declare @CreationTime_;
        declare @CreationUserId_;
        declare @StartDateTime_;        

        SELECT @Identity_= i.Identity_ from inserted i;
        SELECT @Version_= i.Version_ from inserted i;
        SELECT @Identifier_= i.Identifier_ from inserted i;
        SELECT @CreationTime_= i.CreationTime_ from inserted i;
        SELECT @CreationUserId_= i.CreationUserId_ from inserted i;
        SELECT @StartDateTime_= i.StartDateTime_ from inserted i;

        set @Revision_ = @Version_ +1;

 insert into order_db..PeriodicHistory(Identity_,Version_,Revision_,Identifier_,CreationTime_,CreationUserId_,StartDateTime_)

values(@Identity_,@Version_,@Identifier_,@CreationTime_,@CreationUserId_,@StartDateTime_);
end
```

Comment: insert into order_db..PeriodicHistory select ... from inserted ?

Comment: So what is the problem - have you tested it?

Comment: problem is dat adds data to table after update. it should do before update.

Comment: you should be selecting from `deleted` table, which holds the old data.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER PeriodicHistory_TR_U ON Periodic
FOR UPDATE
AS IF update(StartDateTime_)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO     PeriodicHistory(Identity_,Version_,Revision_,Identifier_,CreationTime_,CreationUserId_,StartDateTime_)
    SELECT  d.Identity_,d.Version_,d.Revision_ + 1,d.Identifier_,d.CreationTime_,d.CreationUserId_,d.StartDateTime_
    FROM    deleted d
    JOIN    inserted i
    ON      d.Identity_ = i.Identity_
END
```

This eliminates the need for temporary variables.

Think about what happens if the update on Periodic affects more than one row. The original trigger won't be able to store multiple values...

Also, my revised trigger updates the version in the history table in the same way as your original trigger. You probably want to update the version in the Periodic table and keep the old value in the history. As it is after ten updates you could end up with: Periodic.Version_ = 1
PeriodicHistory.Version_ = 2

Comment: Thanks for your replay. i have now problem with `Revision_` . `Revision_ ` does not increase by every update. what do you think on it? the reason for it is to keep history of all  changes in `Periodic` table.
Consider that we have no `d.Revision_`  in the `periodic` table. Revision is only in the `PeriodicHistory ` table which should be increased every time an update happens.

Comment: Can you give an example of the values you expect to see for `Version_` and `Revision_`  as changes are made please?